# eclipse code window only showing what in the Outline window

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm not sure what configuration I must have selected, but now the code window only shows the item that is selected in the outline window.
I've never seen this behaviour before and it's quite annoying.
Anyone knows how to change that?

Comment: If you're still around a screen shot of te window would be helpful.

Comment: actually I found the config, it's in Preference->Java->Editor check box "Only show the selected Java element", it was checked, I unchecked it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually I found the config, it's in Preference->Java->Editor check box "Only show the selected Java element", it was checked, I unchecked it.

Comment: looks like an insane option to me, but hey, different people have different tastes, I love "virtual word wrap" my colleagues hate it, and it is still missing in Eclipse ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You must have mylyn activated in your editor in the ["Focusing Editor" mode](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Mylyn/User_Guide#Focusing_Editors):

[image]

Unclick that mylyn button and it should work in a more classic way.

Comment: are you talking about the following preferences:
preferences->tasks->context->
views
[]Auto focus navigator views on task activation
[]Auto expand tree views when focused
I unchecked both of them and restarted eclipse... not working

Comment: @Charbel: more directly: click on the button illustrated in the picture in order to un-select it.

Comment: I don't see that button, maybe it's not mylyn

Comment: actually, I can see it on the outline menu, but it's un-selected and greyed out

Comment: actually I found the config, it's in Preference->Java->Editor check box "Only show the selected Java element", it was checked, I unchecked it. I'll answer my question.